# Trying to install Composer on my Mac, Brew is failing

Tags: php, macos, laravel, composer-php, homebrew

I am trying to install Composer to use with Laravel on my Mac and I am following all the instructions I can find, but it's still failing.

Command: `php --version`

> PHP 5.3.26 (cli) (built: Jul 7 2013 19:05:08)

I have php installed, albeit an older version.

Command: `brew install josegonzalez/php/composer`

> composer: Missing PHP53, PHP54 or PHP55 from homebrew-php. Please install one of them before continuing

Requires php .. mm kay fine.

I tried installing the 53-intl that the composer documentation suggested.

Command: `brew install php53-intl`

> Error no available formula for bison27 (dependency of php53-intl)
>   Searching taps...
>   homebrew/versions/bison27

It failed and I dont really understand the response.. so I'll try a new version of php.

Command: `brew install php55`

> Error: You must `brew link libpng' before php55 can be installed

Okay.. Dependency issue.. no problem right?

Command: `brew link libpng`

> Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.18... Warning: Could not link libpng. Unlinking...
>   Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.18/share/man/man3/libpngpf.3
>   /usr/local/share/man/man3 is not writable.  You should change its permissions.

It's 777'd.

I'm kind of at a loss..

I tried unlinking and relinking libpng;
Command: `brew unlink libpng`

> Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.18... 0 links removed

But unlinking didnt' appear to do anything.. and linking gave same error as above.

I have no idea how to proceed.. Thoughts?

Comment: Try running `brew install php53-intl` as suggested in the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally-on-osx-via-homebrew-).

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that I did that;

Command: `brew install php53-intl`

```Error: No available formula for bison27 (dependency of php53-intl)
 Searching taps...
 homebrew/versions/bison27```

It didnt' work either and I am new proficient with brew to know what all that meant

Answer (score 7):

First try:

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
```

Now run brew install php... again

Comment: Solved the same problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to do the following

```
brew untap homebrew/versions
brew update
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew update
```

the extra updates may or may not be necessary but i included them as it was my path to solving this issue!